# Parsing data from text by template

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to get data from string knowning its template?
I mean for example

```
def template = "${person} came up with the idea to collect ${item}."
def text = "Peter came up with the idea to collect coins."
```

And then retrieve `Peter` and `coins`?

Answer (score 0):

If your template is a groovy string (`GString`), then you can access every part of it with the `getStrings()` and `getValues()` methods.

See [the "toString" implementation of a GString](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GString.java#L164)

Comment: But how it connects template and text? I need to extract data from text (not from template but by it).